KKT conditions immediate corollary of Lagrange duality theorem?
I do not see this mentioned in the literature, but it seems that the KKT conditions (and corresponding necessary and sufficient optimality conditions) are essentially a corollary of the Lagrange duality theorem, i.e. the characterization of weak duality (no hypotheses) and strong duality (implied by convexity and CQ).
Is there a reference that derives the KKT conditions and optimality conditions just based on the Lagrange duality theorem?

I think Boyd's convex optimization book shows this, right?

I am not sure, he does not state theorems in the book.

I am looking for a reference that is more precise and to the point than Boyd.

Do you have to derive KKT from duality? I personally feel it's a bit more natural to construct KKT system first, and then go with the duality

How do you construct it? In most references, it seems like KKT just is presented rather than derived.

Yes, that's why I said construct the KKT system first, not really from nowhere. We want the dual objective to serve as a lower bound, and aim to find the best lower bound by maximizing the dual. The complementarity condition is not hard to come up with from the sensitive perspective

I think from a normal cone perspective deriving the KKT is another popular and natural way to go; see e.g., https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/hf323/L22-III-OPT/lecture8.pdf. Note that this is also the starting point of designing constraint qualifications (regularity conditions)
